# How to add timeout on Firebase RemoteConfig fetch request?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, timeout, firebase-remote-config

I am using Firebase Remote Config feature in my app. 
I need to add a network timeout on the fetch request.

```
#if DEBUG
let expirationDuration: TimeInterval = 0
RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().configSettings = RemoteConfigSettings(developerModeEnabled: true)
#else
let expirationDuration: TimeInterval = 3600
#endif

RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().fetch(withExpirationDuration: expirationDuration) {
    [weak self] (status, error) in

    guard error == nil else {
        print ("Uh-oh. Got an error fetching remote values \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

    RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().activateFetched()

    self?.fetchComplete = true
    self?.loadingDoneCallback?()
}
```

How can I do?

Comment: Why do you need a timeout?

Comment: @DougStevenson With a very bad network, my app loads indefinitely and never returns fetchComplete=true

Comment: Your app shouldn't be waiting on the results of the fetch.  You should handle the results asynchronously whenever it's finished.

Comment: My parameters have to be load before launching my home screen.

Comment: I think you're going to have to implement something on your own.  The Firebase APIs won't help you here.

Comment: @DougStevenson ok thanks, do you have an idea to do that?

Answer (score 6):

There's a `fetchTimeout` setting that you can use when you initialise `FIRRemoteConfig.configSettings`.

The documentation and details are [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseremoteconfig/api/reference/Classes/FIRRemoteConfigSettings?authuser=1#fetchtimeout)

Answer (score 5):

You can have a workaround for that by using a timer:

```
  remoteConfigTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10,
                                                 repeats: false) {
                                                    timer in
                                                    self.remoteConfigTimerExpired = true
                                                    self.loadingDoneCallback()
  }
```

Here you define your timeout as the timeInterval of your Timer, and once this timer is reached you just execute the same method you would execute if the RemoteConfig call was successful.

Note that this is only available for iOS 10 or higher.

Comment: Nice solution but I would have added `remoteConfigTimer .invalidate()` in the remote config fetch callback to prevent the timer from firing an error when the fetch was successful.